# Removing certain part of array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove a certain key of my array since I'm creating a filter for my data.

```
Array(
   [0]=>Array
      (
        ['Column1'] => 'ABC'
        ['Column2'] => 'xxx'
      )
   [1]=>Array
      (
        ['Column1'] => 'XYZ'
        ['Column2'] => 'xxx'
      )
)
```

I want to remove the key (meaning the number 2) that has the value 'XYZ'. How can I remove it? I need to remove it because I am filtering the array that was thrown to me by another script and I need to remove the key. I tried using for loop but I do not know how to remove it.

```
for($z = 0; $z < count($array);$z++)
{
   if($array[$z]['Column1'] == 'XYZ'){
          // how do I remove the record [1] and all of its contents?
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to get rid of only `XYZ` or each occurence of `column1`>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unset()

```
for($z = 0; $z < count($array);$z++)
{
   if($array[$z]['Column1'] == 'XYZ'){
     unset($array[$z]);
  }
}
```

You can also do:

```
foreach($array as &$v) {
  if($v['Column1'] == 'XYZ') {
    unset($v);
  }
}
```

After using unset() on an array, and as long as you don't need to retain the index values, it is worth doing:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

To reset the array index.

Comment: @marchemike for this solution, after the loop it is good to use $array = array_values($array); to re-base the array indexes as it can leave empty values in indexes where you have unset the value. But that may be your desired result, up to you

Comment: Got it working now. +1 for array_values as i need that to reorganize the array as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    if ($v['Column1'] == 'XYZ') unset($array[$k]);
}
```